# Problem playing music and sound effects in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm new to Cocos2d-x and working on a mac. I'm trying to play music in my demo project but I'm unable to include "SimpleAudioEngine.h" in the default HelloWorld Project. I tried adding CocosDenshion to my project but I got more errors. Anyone who knows how to fix this please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add CocosDenshion, which is the audio library. Be sure the link is done correctly or copypaste it into your folder and use <> import just in case

```
#include <SimpleAudioEngine.h>
```

Once you have it correctly linked the functions used are quite trivial:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("stuff.wav");
```

Be sure to be using [the supported formats in each platform](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Audio_formats_supported_by_CocosDenshion_on_different_platforms)

Comment: In the default HelloWorld project CocosDenshion is not there so I'm unable to include SimpleAudioEngine.h I tried adding the folder to project in xcode but now I'm getting compiler errors. The best way i found till now is installing the template and then creating a new project.

Comment: Don't add the folder, just the SimpleAudioEngine.h library in your Class folder, and include it with <>. The rest of the libraries are compiled and linked together and they don't have to be inside the HelloWorld folder.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong can't get SimpleAudioEngine to work with HelloWorldpProject. Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: Sadly I cannot send you my code, but the tutorial I used as reference is http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_6_-_How_to_Play_Music_and_Sound_Effect I solved the linking problem the way I showed you, but the include is probably the cause.